# How to make Alacritty as default terminal on Macos

Tags: macos, iterm2, alacritty

I just want to know how to make Alacritty as default terminal on Macos.

I hope Alacritty launches like iTerm2 when I click "Open in Terminal" in the Finder.

Answer (score 0):

There is an imperfect approach：

Open your `Terminal`, than go to `Preference`

At `Gerneral`'s `Shells open with:`

Set the value of `Command (complete path):` as : `/opt/homebrew/bin/alacritty`
(if you install alacritty by homebrew)

[my preference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mNIv.png)

Then, you open in terminal, it will open terminal first, then open alacritty.

and I don't know what param the finder pass to terminal, so I am also find the way to solve it.